# How i can store image in database using C#?

Tags: sql-server, wpf, database, image-processing, c#-4.0

This is my C# code which print the image in Grid(WPF) and Now i want to 
store this image in Database,I have the column in database with the name of 
Image.I have all other code database connection etc.Kindly tell me which 
method is best for store image in database?

```
 private void button_Browse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
        op.Title = "Select a picture";
        op.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
          "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
          "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";
        if (op.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
        imgPhoto.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));//this line print image in Grid

        }
    }
```

Comment: ***WHAT*** database? This is heavily dependent upon which concrete database system you're talking about ......

Comment: @marc_s SQl Server Database at column datatype is image.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @marc_s If I use varchar(max) or carbinary(max) then how i will convert image type into varchar(max) or other

Comment: For **binary** data (like an image), use `varbinary(max)` - and you should be able to simply convert the column's datatype with a `ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourColumn VARBINARY(MAX);`

Comment: @marc_s ok i did it and convert column type in varbinary but now in C# how i can convert image into binary?Do you have any idea sir?

Comment: First step: look at the ***MANY*** questions and answers that have already been provided here : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+store+image

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VARBINARY(MAX)` to store files of any type:

I'm giving you an example by myself, hope it helps.

First create a table(say **tblSampleImage**) then add two columns(**FileName VARCHAR(20)** , **FileContent VARBINARY(MAX)**)

*Below is a sample CS code for inserting and fetching file from database:*

```
public void insertFile()
{
   string fileName= Path.GetFileName(@"your file full path");
   string filePath= Path.GetFullPath(@"your file full path");
   if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File not found");
                return;
            }
    byte[] contents= File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    string insertStmt = "INSERT INTO tblSampleImage(FileName, FileContent) VALUES(@FileName, @FileContent)";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = "connectionString";
    using (SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand(insertStmt, connection))
          {
          cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = fileName;
          cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@FileContent", SqlDbType.VarBinary, int.MaxValue).Value = contents;
          connection.Open();
          cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
           connection.Close();
          }   
}
```

**To Fetch File**

```
   public void fetchFile()
        {
        string newFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(@"your new path where you store your fetched file");
        string fileName="File1"; //this is the file's name which is stored in database and you want to fetch
         byte[] fileContents;
         string selectStmt = "SELECT FileContent FROM tblSampleImage WHERE FileName = @FileName";
         SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
         connection.ConnectionString = "connectionString";
         using (SqlCommand cmdSelect = new SqlCommand(selectStmt, connection))
            {
               cmdSelect.Parameters.Add("@Filename", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fileName;
               connection.Open();
               fileContents = (byte[])cmdSelect.ExecuteScalar();
               connection.Close();
            }
         File.WriteAllBytes(newFilePath, fileContents);
         MessageBox.Show("File Saved at:  " + newFilePath);
    }
```